# create multiple object in one form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

What i'm trying to achive is a web page that looks something like a nested form (so with the ability to add new elements and remove those which already exist). The problem here is that it is not a nested form, instead I have only one model.

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and i want to create and edit/create/update page (all in one)... my controller for now looks something like this

```
def configure
  @config_items = MyModel.all
end
```

this is the rendering page

```
def config_update
  @config_items = MyModel.all
  errors = save_configs
  respond_to do |format|
    if errors.empty?
      flash[:success] = "message"
      format.html { redirect_to root_path}
      format.json { render json: @config_items, status: :ok }
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "message"
      format.html { render :configure }
      format.json { render json: ?what?, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the update action

```
def save_configs
   @config_items = []
   errors = []
   params[:config_items].each do |id, name|
     item = MyModel.find_or_create_by(id: id)
     errors << item.errors unless item.update_attributes(name: name[:name])
     @config_items << item
   end
   errors
 end
def config_params
  params.require(:config_items).permit(:id,
                                       :name
                                      )
end
```

with it's methods

```
<%= form_with url: update_configs_members_path do |form| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'type', params[:type] %>
    <div id="items" class="col-md-12 p-0 pl-md-3">
      <% @config_items.each do |config| %>
        <%= form.fields_for "config_items[]", config do |configForm| %>
          <%= render 'config_fields', f: configForm %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag 'Update Configurations', class: 'btn btn-warning btn-block my-2' %>
  <% end %>
```

this is my current view (the configure view)

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field form-group row">
    <%= f.label :name, 'Name:', class: 'col-sm-1 col-form-label' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control ml-2' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 p-0">
      <%= link_to "&times;".html_safe, ?destroy_field?, class: 'badge badge-pill badge-danger mt-2' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the partial

At this current stage I can easly update each instance of my model that already exist, but what I want is a way to destroy and create new record. so the question is how do i do that? (if possible I would like to use the cocoon gem)

Comment: if you want to delete, just pass '_destroy' hidden boolean value, if create - 'id' should be nil. Of course it's not automatic - the code should be written

Comment: Why is your model named `myModel` and not `MyModel`?

Comment: yeah @NeverBe, but the question is how, cause that's what i am struggling with... otherwise i wouldn't have posted the question...